# "gnome-shell-extensions" Not able to upload the complete directory

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

First of all, I am sorry If this is not the rite place to ask.

Recently, I tried to upload the extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2935/control-blur-effect-on-lock-screen/ to the extensions.gnome.org website.

this link says to make `zip -j` https://extensions.gnome.org/upload/ to create the zip file. Then to upload.

when I make the zip file with `zip -r` and try to upload.. It returns error that `metadata.json` file is not loaded and fails to upload though this file exists.

I must do `zip -r` to have the compatibility to work the shell extension installed with the command `gnome-extensions install nameOfTheExtension`

Where as I have seen some gnome-shell-extensions downloaded from the same website are having this.. I mean when you create a zip file with `zip -r`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files must be in the top-level of the Zip:

- `metadata.json`
- `extension.js`
- `prefs.js` (Optional file)
- `stylesheet.css` (Optional file)

That is the only requirement. The `-r` and `-j` functions are explained by `zip --help`:

> `-j   junk (don't record) directory names`
>
> `-r   recurse into directories`

If all your extension files are in one, top-level directory then `-j` will work, otherwise it will probably break your directory hierarchy. You can check the layout of a zip with `unzip -l`.

Typically you will zip with `zip -r extension@domain.zip [path with metadata.json]`:

```sh
$ ls
extensions.js  metadata.json

$ zip -r extension@domain.zip .
  adding: metadata.json (deflated 33%)
  adding: extension.js (deflated 55%)

$ unzip -l extension@domain.zip 
Archive:  extension@domain.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      194  04-25-2020 17:47   metadata.json
      864  04-25-2020 17:47   extension.js
---------                     -------
     1058                     2 files
```

Comment: rite now i am using `zip -r extension@123.mail.zip extension@123.mail/*`

Comment: Thanks.. I was missing `zip -r extension@domain.zip .` This. Thanks a lot @andy.holmes

Answer (score 0):

To complement what andy.holmes suggested, the easiest way to package the extension (which might have a directory inside) is to zip it from inside the extension directory. In my case the directory was the `schemas`.

Directory structure:

```
└── my-extension@domain.com
    ├── extension.js
    ├── metadata.json
    └── schemas
        ├── gschemas.compiled
        └── org.gnome.shell.extensions.my-extension.gschema.xml
```

Zipping:

```
cd my-extension@domain.com
zip -r my-extension@domain.com.zip *
```

Short bash script for building the zip:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

TMP_EXTENSION=/tmp/my-extension

# Cleanup previous build
rm -rf $TMP_EXTENSION
rm -f my-extension@domain.com.zip

cp -r my-extension@domain.com $TMP_EXTENSION

# Remove redundant content
rm -rf $TMP_EXTENSION/.git/

cd $TMP_EXTENSION
zip -r my-extension@domain.zip *
```